# Lodash shuffle function can't be animated in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I was unable to make `lodash`'s shuffle method animate in Vue.js, even though I have copied the code from the documentation...

Shuffle happens, but not with animation. I have tested the animation by actually removing items from the array, and animation works, but when I use shuffle method, it just instantly happens instead of smoothly.

Component:

```
<transition-group name="list">
 <span class="letter" v-for="(letter, key) in data" :key="key">
    {{ letter }}
 </span>
</transition-group>
```

What happens when you click "shuffle" button :

```
 shuffleLetters : function(){
   this.data = shuffle(this.data)
 }
```

Animation code :

```
.list-move, /* apply transition to moving elements */
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.list-enter-from,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

/* ensure leaving items are taken out of layout flow so that moving
   animations can be calculated correctly. */
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use the array index as a `:key`. Vue won't make a difference between `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 1]` because the index is generating on the `v-for` loop, it's not tied to an element.

Try to bind a relevant `:key` from each element and it should starts animating.